# Minus in Landau Notation

Tags: analysis, notation

Quick question: When using Landau symbols, does it matter whether we write
$ f = (1 + o(g)) $
or
$ f = (1 - o(g)) $
?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you mean. One usually disregard constants, so we rather write $o(g)$ instead of $2o(g)$ or $-o(g)$. But when $g$ is positive one could write $f=1-o(g)$ to emphasize that $f$ is at most $1$.

Comment: Thank you! In the book I'm using, both $f=(1+o(1))$ and $f=(1-o(1))$ are used. So, I guess, in the first case they mean that $f$ is bigger than $1$ and in the second case that $f$ is smaller than $1$?

Comment: It might also mean that in the case $f=1+o(1)$, we don't know whether $f\ge1$ or $f\le  1$. It should be explained in the book.

Comment: In a calculation like $2-(1+o(g))$ it's most natural to write the result as $1-o(g)$ although $1+o(g)$ is generally more convenient and equivalent.